# A Hessian matrix (convex function) question. Given $u \in C^2(\mathbb{D}, \mathbb{R})$ s.t. $u(x) \geq \frac{1}{1-||x||^2}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

Given $u \in C^2(\mathbb{D}, \mathbb{R})$ such that

$$u(x) \geq \frac{1}{1-||x||^2}$$

And let $\Omega$ be the set of points where the hessian matrix, $Hu \geq 0$. Prove or disprove that $Du: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is surjective

It is pretty natural to see that $u|_{\Omega}$ is a convex function by the theorem:

Theorem: Given a convex region $D \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and function $f \in C^2(D, \mathbb{R})$, the epigraph is convex iff $H f \geq 0$ for $x \in D$.

How should I continue on this?

Comment: you could prove that for all vectors $g$  the minimization problem $\min_{x\in D} u(x) - g^Tx$ is solvable with solution $x^*$. Then $\nabla u(x^*)=g$.